# String to char array Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am stumped on this and I need some fresh eyes, I'm not sure why this code is doing this.

```
String string = new String(new char[] {(char) 0x01, (char) 0x02, ... ,(char) 0xFC});
```

The output is everything it should be up until the last number (the 0xFC) it returns a -4,
I know its a hex value, but if I do the same with 252 the decimal value, it gives me a negative as well.  I hope this is just a simple solution, and I just can't see it.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: what are you trying to return?

Comment: So you are trying to creating a String _from_ a character array?

Comment: `0xFC` is a positive integer; the `char` type is not signed. The resultant codepoint is U+00FC - Latin Small Letter U With Diaeresis. How are you outputting the String?

Comment: 0xFC results in 252, not -4 here http://ideone.com/cIi9J

Answer (score 159, accepted):

A string to char array is as simple as

```
String str = "someString"; 
char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
```

Can you explain a little more on what you are trying to do?

*** Update ***

if I am understanding your new comment, you can use a byte array and example is provided.

```
byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(1695609641).array();

for (byte b : bytes) {
   System.out.format("0x%x ", b);
}
```

With the following output

0x65 0x10 0xf3 0x29

Comment: I am trying to send a packet with a byte array or char array to get specific values to the device I have on my closed network.  I am making an app remote.  just need that array in 9 bytes, to give the specific hex or decimal values.

Comment: A nice shortcut of the above is "string".toCharArray(). It can save you a line of code.