# Android Edittext Values in array

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-edittext

i am developing an android app in which 1 edit text is there... the first edittext is to give firstname of the user .. in which letters are entered for example first name of users... and for each letter different values are given ... my question how to add all these values.... ?

HOW TO take each letters individually.....and put into an array and add all its values

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btn1;
    EditText et1, et2, et3, et4, et5, et6;
    Spinner sp1,sp2,sp3;
    TextView txt1,txt2,txt3,txt4,txt5,txt6,txt7,txt8,txt9,txt10;
    String month,day,year;
    int sum;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void calc(View v)
    {

        EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
        /*TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById ( R.id.textView88);*/
        sum=getSum(et1.getText().toString());
        Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this, result.class);
        i.putExtra("name", sum);
        startActivity(i);

        /*txt1.setText(sum + "");*/


    }

    private int getSum(String text) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int sum = 0;
        char[] name = new char[text.length()];
        name = text.toCharArray();

        for(int i=0; i<text.length(); i++)
        {
            sum += value( name[i] );
        }
        while (sum>9)
        {
            sum = findDigitSum(sum);
        }

        return sum;
    }



    public int findDigitSum(int n) 
    {
        int sum = 0;
        while (n != 0) 
        {
            sum += n % 10;
            n = n / 10;
        }
        return sum;
    }
    private int value(char a) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(a) {
        case 'A': 
           return 1;
        case 'B':
           return 2;
        case 'C':
           return 3;
        case 'D': 
            return 4;
         case 'E':
            return 5;
         case 'F':
            return 6; 
         case 'G': 
             return 7;
          case 'H':
             return 8;
          case 'I':
             return 9;
          case 'J': 
              return 1;
          case 'K':
              return 2;
           case 'L':
              return 3;
           case 'M': 
               return 4;
            case 'N':
               return 5;
            case 'O':
               return 6; 
            case 'P': 
                return 7;
             case 'Q':
                return 8;
             case 'R':
                return 9;
             case 'S': 
                 return 1;
             case 'T':
                 return 2;
              case 'U':
                 return 3;
              case 'V': 
                  return 4;
               case 'W':
                  return 5;
               case 'X':
                  return 6; 
               case 'Y': 
                   return 7;
                case 'Z':
                   return 8;
                 default:
            return 0;
    }





}
}
```

the second activity
result.java

```
public class result extends Activity {

    TextView txt2;
    /*private Intent getIntent;*/



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.result_xm);
        TextView txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        txt2.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("name"));
        /*Intent iin= getIntent();
        Bundle b = iin.getExtras();
        if(b!=null)
        {
            String name = getIntent.getStringExtra("name");
            txt2.setText(name);
        }*/
    }

}
```

Logcat details

```
08-26 20:25:47.579: E/Trace(1873): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-26 20:25:49.179: D/dalvikvm(1873): GC_CONCURRENT freed 39K, 6% free 2788K/2948K, paused 19ms+89ms, total 195ms
08-26 20:25:50.311: I/Choreographer(1873): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-26 20:25:50.579: D/gralloc_goldfish(1873): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-26 20:27:38.388: D/dalvikvm(1873): GC_CONCURRENT freed 125K, 8% free 3049K/3296K, paused 81ms+21ms, total 257ms
08-26 20:27:40.869: I/Choreographer(1873): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-26 20:27:42.209: D/AndroidRuntime(1873): Shutting down VM
08-26 20:27:42.229: W/dalvikvm(1873): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
08-26 20:27:42.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1873): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-26 20:27:42.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1873): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.numerology/com.example.numerology.result}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-26 20:27:42.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
08-26 20:27:42.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-26 20:27:42.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-26 20:27:42.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
08-26 20:27:42.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-26 20:27:42.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-26 20:27:42.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-26 20:27:42.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-26 20:27:42.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-26 20:27:42.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-26 20:27:42.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-26 20:27:42.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-26 20:27:42.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1873): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-26 20:27:42.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at com.example.numerology.result.onCreate(result.java:19)
08-26 20:27:42.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-26 20:27:42.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-26 20:27:42.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
08-26 20:27:42.349: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: 1 EditText has 1 value - a `String`. How / Why do you want to split that into multiple values and  put them into an array?

Comment: i need to find the numerological value of name... for that different letters have different values ... so when user enter his first name all the text have to be taken and the values has to add each other and find the resulted value

Comment: @ Rachit do u know how to do it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048899/string-to-char-array-java - you can treat a `char` as a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Write your activity code as:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void sum(View v) {
            int sum =0;
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    sum = getSum(editText.getText().toString());

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText(sum + "");
}
public int getSum(String text) {
    int sum = 0;
    char[] name = new char[text.length()]; // where length is maximum length
                                            // of name.
    name = text.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        sum += value(name[i]);
    }

    // check if sum is greater than 9
    while (sum > 9) {
        sum = findDigitSum(sum);
    }
    return sum;
}

   // find sum of digits if sum is greater than 9

public int findDigitSum(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    while (n != 0) {
        sum += n % 10;
        n = n / 10;
    }
    return sum;
}
// return value for char
public int value(char a) {
    switch (a) {
        case 'c' :
            return 7;
        case 'a' :
            return 3;
        case 't' :
            return 9;
        case 'e' :
            return 2;
        default :
            return 0;
    }
}
```

}

Write your layout file activity_main.cml as:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
     </EditText>

     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Sum"
    android:onClick="sum" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Now clicking the button shows you the sum in textView.

Comment: @ Rachit... i think this will work... thanks a lot... let me check.... and if any doubt I will reply....

Comment: oh okay :) ! no probs !

Comment: i am not getting the result... i need to display the value in a text view ... how will display it...pls check this is it correct

Comment: TextView tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv1.setText(string);

Comment: pls check the full code.. i edited it in my question ...as u given

Comment: I have updated my answer for full code of activity and layout.

Comment: @ Rachit ... thanks ... thanks a lot... and i am appreciating your patience... to do all this for me.... I think u will help me in future also .... thanks 4 u r help ... its working very fine....

Comment: learning experience friend :) , ask if you need more help anywhere :)

Comment: @ Rachit ... one more help ... here the result can be more than 9 but the result must be below 10 ..for example the total result is 10 then 1 + 0 = 1 and 11 is 1 + 1 =2 like... so what i hav to do that

Comment: hai rachit in this result if we are giving value for c that is 3 then it will go to 10 and 11 after we will get result like 3.. but upto 11 it is coming

Comment: not getting you ? the value of c can be changed ! and i edited the code again, using local variables so we get different values for different names like cat = 6, at = 3, c = 3, ca = 4

Comment: no .. the problem is when this value is adding if the result is 10 then value must be displayed as 1 and for 11 it must be 2 but for these 2 numbers the result is displayed as 10 and 11 but for 12 it is displayed as 3 ... so the problem is when the result is 10 or 11 instead of displaying as 1 and 2 it is displaying as 10 and 11 ... that is the problem.....

Comment: edited the answer again with new test cases; it works for me !

Comment: OH SORRY RACHITH JUST CHECK FOR NAME 'DHARMADEVAN' THE VALUE IS 10 AND THE RESULT IS DISPLAYING AS 10 ONLY... AND I F YOU ADD AN 'A' TO THE NAME THE RESULT WILL BE 11 AND LIKE THAT IT WILL GO UPTO 13...AND AFTER THAT NO PROBLEM

Comment: hmm.. yes actually it evaluates sum just for once, i.e in `if(sum>9)`, but actually it has to be re-evaluated again, so that result is always less than 9, please change `if(sum>9)` to `while(sum>9)`, it will work okay,  again I update the code.

Comment: thanks Rachit...its working....another help needed ... do u know how to display this result in a textview on another screen .. for example in another page...Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , girl.class);
             startActivity(intent); I know this code...but this only go to another page called girl.class..but i need the result to be printed in the page in a textview.... I hope u help me...

Comment: In first activity:
`startActivity(new Intent(this , girl.class).putExtra("sum", sum+"");`
In the another activity get data as:
`String sum = getIntent().getStringExtra("from", 0)`

Comment: how we connect it to the textview... for example in the second activity it has to be displayed in id called textView2.

Comment: TextView tv = (TextView) finViewById (R.id.textView1);
tv.setText(sum);

Comment: k...thanks Rachit...u r really a genius.. I think ..u will be a good friend for me to study more in this android application development... thanks a lot once again.. for your kind help...

Comment: hi rachit ... can u pls check my edited code... I updated... in my question ... that is first activities... when executed and the calculate button is pressed ... the application is stopping unfortunately...can u pls check for any errors..is ther or not..

Comment: `i.putExtra("name", sum+""); //as sum is not String, but a integer`

Comment: Now also the same error is showing ... the second activity is edited in the code... can u pls check....

Comment: the error is when calculate button is pressed a window is coming with mesage 'unfortunately, num is stopped'

Comment: no friend, check the error from logcat, what you see is an app crash, check logcat to see why it crashes, the error is shown in red

Comment: see it is the error i told you, sum is not a string, it an integer

`i.putExtra("name", sum);` change this too `i.putExtra("name", sum+"");`

Comment: one more advice, edit your question and hide your logic now, so that it is not exposed to others.

Comment: ya... i changed... it ... but after that also the error is coming... I will update the new logcat details now

Comment: now its a different error :) and its in 2nd activity 

`String name = getIntent.getStringExtra("name");`

get the value like this.

Comment: I edited the second activity can u pls check...when I executed...the same error is coming

Comment: After you initialise `txt2` just write this 
`txt2.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("name");`

Comment: the same msg is coming

Comment: This runs fine at my side, here is code of MainActivity http://pastebin.com/zbdGFmXW and the Result Activity http://pastebin.com/Bn7NTTGT

Comment: so gye kya roshan bhai ... :)

Comment: hi...friend....now the first name we got... now i need to calculate the same for edit text of lastname and also add it with firstnames value and dsiplay the result...can u help...?

Comment: Hi.. friend...I got it....sum=getSum(et1.getText().toString() + et2.getText().toString() + et3.getText().toString() + et4.getText().toString() )  ;I did like this

Comment: Hi... Friend... i have another doubt ... I have to do the same first name to be calculate for vowels only... means .. only values of vowels  has to be calculated and the value must be displayed in another textview in second page..( actiivity )

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a [Autocomplete Text View](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-autocompletetextview-example). Please go through the link for detailed implementation of Autocomplete Text View.