# Read input string

Tags: java

I'm just new in Java and I would like to ask if it's possible to separate each letter of a word. For example, my input is "ABCD" and I would like to display each letter of that word. So, the expected output should be. The input word consists of letters: "A", "B", "C", "D". Sorry, I am just very new in Java and I would like to know if this is possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting String to “Character” array in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006165/converting-string-to-character-array-in-java)

Comment: `"ABCD".split("")` - This won't give you an array of `char`, instead you get an array of `String`, but the first and last elements in the array are the empty string. Depending on the application, the fact your letters start at index 1 and the last one is an empty string can be nice things while processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String.toCharArray()
```

is the method you are  looking for

It will create an Array of Chars. So your string would become

```
{'A','B','C','D'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its possible to split your String into individual characters. Below is the method to do it :

```
String str = "ABCD";

// this will create Array of all chars in the String
char[] chars = str.toCharArray(); 

// Now loop through the char array and perform the desired operations
for(char val : chars)
{
  // do something
  // variable val will have individual characters
}
```

Comment: On a side note, please try going through the API's and some tutorials it will help in improving your understanding of the language

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you use the String.toCharArray() method ( here's the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) ).

Learn more here - [String to char array Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048899/string-to-char-array-java)

example:

```
String happy = "Yaya happee";
char[] happier = happy.toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use String methods. (`length() and charAt(int index)`)
I think you are new at programming so using String methods are better for you if you do not know arrays.