# How do I make my porgram sift through a users input (using the Scanner library) character-by-character?

Tags: java, encoding, java.util.scanner, decoding

I am writing a small program for a highschool class, and want to take a user's input (EX: "Hello"), divide it into seperate characters ("hello" --> "h","e","l","l","o"), then shift the characters over one place in the alphabet ("Hello" --> "Ifmmp"). Is there an easy way to do this using java?

Comment: btw, the first letter of "lfmmp" is an I, not a lower-case L, just saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to realise is that the `char` type in java (representing a single character) is treated as a number (you can look up an ASCII table for the number values of regular characters).

So the process would be to go through all the characters in the original `String` and for each of these you add 1 to it. If these all are added to a second `String` that one will contain all the characters shifted one step.

```
String originalString = "hello";
// Use a StringBuilder to save all the characters
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

for (char c : originalString.toCharArray()) {
  // Add 1 to each character and append it
  builder.append((char) (c + 1));
}

// Now the builder contains the String with the shifted values
System.out.println(builder);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Scanner` with an empty delimiter to retrieve the characters :

```
String in = "abc";
Scanner s = new Scanner(in);
s.useDelimiter("");
while (s.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(s.next());
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Aaron. Just to clarify, could you tell me _italic_  how _italic_ this code works. Im new to Java.

Comment: Haha, sorry about the italics, ignore them

Comment: @Justin The scanner's `.hasNext()` and `.next()` methods work with tokens, which are parts of the parsed strings that are separated by the delimiter the scanner uses. The empty string can be found around every character, so using it as a delimiter will make it possible to iterate over the characters of an input `String`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast your string into an array of characters then loop through it and increment each character. Look at the post below.
[String to char array Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048899/string-to-char-array-java)

Comment: this works well, but I really need it to asign the letters to different variables, then translate them one letter to the left or right in the normal alphabet

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need the Scanner to go through the string. You could use a Scanner to get the users input, though. Then you just look at the String char by char and manipulate them. But be careful: In this example, when the char is "z" or "Z", it will be changed into the wrong char. So you'll have to deal with the ascii-codes appropriately:

```
char[] chars = "abc".toCharArray();

for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    chars[i] = (char) (chars[i] + 1);
}

String s = new String(chars);
System.out.println(s);
```

prints out:

`bcd`

Answer (score 0):

### Introduction

We’ll make use of the `Scanner` as usual to scan for user input using `nextLine`. Upon having retrieved the user input, we’ll convert it over to an array of `char`s and check each `char` with `char`s contained by an alphabet array.

If it turns out the input `String` contains a number—that symbol will be replaced with an `a`—should you not want this behavior, I’m sure you can figure out how to change that on your own.

### Implementation

The following is what we’ll do:

```
// Scanner to scan for user input
// Array of ‘char’s containing entire alphabet
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
char[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
char[] input = scanner.nextLine().toCharArray();

// Go over chars inside input
for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i ++)
{
    char c = input[i];

    // Go over alphabet in search for corresponding char
    // As ‘t + 1’ will generate an error if ‘t == alphabet.length - 1’
    // we do not go over that—instead we cover that after the loop
    for(int t = 0; t < alphabet.length - 1; t ++)
        if(c == alphabet[t])
        {
            input[i] = alphabet[t + 1];

            break;
        }

    // If alphabet ‘t’ was equal to ‘alphabet.length - 1’ or the symbol
    // was not located by the alphabet—say input contained a number
    if(c == input[i])
        input[i] = alphabet[0];
}

// Print out result
System.out.println("Input is: " + new String(input));

// Close scanner
scanner.close();
```

This will only work for [lower case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case) letters. But checking for upper case letters as well wouldn’t be further away than creating another alphabet array of `char`s containing the upper case alphabet.

Should you want the implementation slightly more readable, may I suggest you put the ‘go over alphabet’ in a separate method?

### Moreover

The implementation is rather simple, but I’m sure you can build on top of it!

Comment: Thanks, this really cleared the concept up! (That was sincerity, not mockery)